# Command Problem in ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, apt, dpkg

I can not use this command `sudo apt-get install w64codecs`.

The terminal shows this:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg), is another process using it?
```

[image]

Comment: Please see here... http://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process

Answer (score 2):

What's likely happening is that the software updater is running and checking for updates.  Only one program at a time can access the packages cache.

Usually if you wait long enough for the updater to finish, it will work again.

Answer (score 1):

Another process is currently using `dpkg`. This happens if any command using `apt-get` is currently running, or some other program that locks this file (such as `aptitude`, `synaptic`, `gdebi`, or `dpkg`).

It also can happen if you start an installation but then force it to stop. Waiting for the current installation to finish or **restarting your computer** can solve this issue.